# Is there a way for a button background color to remain changed after being selected?

Tags: swiftui

The following code changes the button background color when pressed, but goes back to original background when when released. I would like the button to remain selected.

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .padding()
      .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white : Color("greenColor"))
      .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.clear)
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that by introducing state in button style and make style changes dependent on it, while updating state conditionally when needed.

[image: demo]

Here is main part of approach (tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4)

```
    .background(flag ? Color.red : Color.clear)
    .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) {
        if $0 {
            flag.toggle()
        }
    }
```

Completed [report and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/ButtonStyle_with_State.md)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, not using a custom button. Just keeping track of a `State` variable if button is tapped do something. The first button uses a `plain` style with `cornerRadius`, the second button use the `borderedProminent` style but this shows with a highlight on button tap.

[image: button]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstbutton: Bool = false
    @State var secondbutton: Bool = false
    // AppStorage saves state when app is killed
    //@AppStorange("tapped") var tapped: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            firstbutton.toggle()
            /*
             if once
             toggle = true
             */
        }, label: {
            Label("Button", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                .foregroundColor(firstbutton ? Color.white : Color.green)
                .padding(.all, 10)
        })
        .background(firstbutton ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
        
        
        Button(action: {
            secondbutton.toggle()
            /*
             if once
             toggle = true
             */
        }, label: {
            Label("Button", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                .foregroundColor(secondbutton ? Color.white : Color.green)
                .padding(.all, 10)
        })
        .tint(secondbutton ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```